# Limiting a result using PHP, without using LIMIT clause when fetching rows in database query?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, limit

I have a table in SQL, it contains around 100 rows.

I select it within PHP with `SELECT * FROM table`.

I didn't use offset nor limit. My question now is, is there are way to manipulate the returned result using only PHP to display only like 24 rows from the table?

What should I try?

Comment: [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice)? have you tried that? The best method, would to limit within SQL.

Comment: foreach($result as $k => $row){if($k < 24){do whatever}}  ???

Comment: FWIW, it's understandable that someone may assume you're using MySQL (or PostgreSQL or SQLite) since you mentioned "limit" and "offset" but did not tag your question with Oracle (I have added that tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess now that the `oracle` tag was added, I'll add the oracle answer.

```
$rows = array(row, row, row, ...); // from oracle sql results
$first_24_rows = array_slice($rows, 0, 24);
```

Comment: i have a different solution that has solved the problem...but i will choose your answer as the best answer ...thanks though

Answer (score 2):

The general format for getting rows from the DB looks like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    echo $row['column_name'] . "\n";
}
```

You'll want to modify it like this:

```
$limit = 24;
while ($limit-- && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    echo $row['column_name'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: am not using mysql..it's oracle... let's say this $variable already has all the data that I need, but the count is 100...so how to only display 24 items of that object?

Comment: example with `mysql_*`? In any case the concept still works fine, +1.

Comment: I just googled "php mysql example" and copied the first thing I saw.

Comment: i just said.. i have this $variable that has all the data that I need..and I am not using mysql..I am using oracle.... and I am not using LIMIT clause to get the 100 result...is there a way to only show 24 objects of that result using only PHP ?

Answer (score -1):

You can control the number of rows return in the oracle SQL itself. Put something like this in the where clause:

and rownum <= 23