# How to GROUP BY a new index in a new VIEW

Tags: sql, view, group-by

I have 2 tables (load+road) and I want to make a new view with creating new column (flag) that indexate the COUNT of the lines, and then GROUP BY this new index.
I have tried this: (but it doesnt work)

```
sprintf(my_cmd, 
"CREATE VIEW myVIEW(id, Rlength, Llength, flag) AS "
"SELECT road.id, road.length, load.length, COUNT(*) AS flag 
FROM road, load "
"WHERE road.id=load.id; "
"SELECT id, Rlength, Llength 
FROM myVIEW"
"GROUP BY flag");
```

ERROR:
Error executing query: ERROR:  column "road.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I am using MY SQL.

*edit:

I dont want that the new column (flag) appears in the last SELECT, but I want to group by it.. dont know if it can be done. if not, the thing I wanna reach, is to use group by on "SELECT id, Rlength, Llength " and to get all the lines in an only one group, but I dont have a Common parameter between thees lines so I have trying to add this "flag"

the full code (sorry for long question):

```
sprintf(my_cmd, 
"CREATE VIEW myVIEW3(id, Rlength, Llength, flag) AS"
" SELECT road.id, road.length, load.length, COUNT(*) AS flag 
FROM road, load"
" WHERE road.id=load.id;"
" SELECT id, Rlength, Llength FROM myVIEW3"
" GROUP BY flag"
" HAVING COUNT(*) <= %d"
" ORDER BY (CAST(Llength AS float) / CAST(Rlength AS float)) DESC, id DESC",k);
```

and what I am trying to do, is to get first k lines after making some ORDER without using LIMIT/TOP (its an assigment). So I have tried using new VIEW with some indecator that I will use for grouping all lines into one group and then use HAVING COUNT(flag) <= k.

road:

.--------.----------------.----------------.
|   Id   |     length     |     speed      | 
.--------.----------------.----------------.-

### | 9      |      55        |      90        |

### |   10   |       44       |      80        |

### |   11   |       70       |      100        |

load:

.--------.----------------.----------------.
|   Id   |     length     |     speed      | 
.--------.----------------.----------------.-

### | 9      |      10        |      20        |

### |   10   |       15       |      30        |

### |   11   |       30       |      60        |

COMMAND:
 loadRanking 2
 (k=2, so I want to get first 2 lines after some ORDER, lets not talk about the ORDER in this result)

result:

.--------.----------------.----------------.
|   Id   |     length     |     speed      | 
.--------.----------------.----------------.-

### | 9      |      10/55     |      20/90     |

### |   10   |       15/44    |      30/80     |

Comment: You really should show us some sample output of what you want to get.  We cannot give you a query with certainty otherwise.

Comment: ok I will edit. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your group by should contain all columns that are being selected that are not part of the aggregate function. So your GROUP BY should look like this:

```
GROUP BY road.id, road.length, load.length
```

That being said, I am quite confused by why you have two queries here. I suspect your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT road.id, road.length, load.length, COUNT(*) AS flag 
FROM road, load 
WHERE road.id=load.id
GROUP BY road.id, road.length, load.length
HAVING COUNT(*) <= %d
 ORDER BY (CAST(load.length AS float) / CAST(road.length AS float)) DESC, road.id DESC
```

[The GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Additional note: Try making sure your query works before making it into a view.

Comment: Oh you want the min and max per id? Let me see what I can figure out for you.

Comment: it is not about the id... I just want to get first k lines without using LIMIT

Comment: I don't have enough rep to respond to your original post. I still don't quite understand what you want. Where is speed coming from? Are you just looking to combine the two tables? Why wasn't id of 11 included in the result? I think if you posted the actual assignment question, I could guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Is it possible the question wants you to use PHP to limit the results? Something like this? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17070820/3843101](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17070820/3843101)

Comment: I want to limit without using LIMIT , yes. but what is PHP ? I am using MY SQL in c .

Comment: Ah sorry, I just googled sprintf() ant noticed it was a PHP function and found a similar request on stackoverflow.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of how to do this is something like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select).